# Rails + Devise: Undefined Local Variable in UserRegistration#Edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

## UPDATE:

I needed to put my controller code **ABOVE** super, like so and then I had access to the @company instance variable in the view:

**User Registration Controller:**

```
class UserRegistrationController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters
  skip_before_filter :load_customer_access, only: [:new, :create]  

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :current_password, :password, :password_confirmation, :email) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :current_password, :password, :password_confirmation, :email) }
  end

  def edit
    @customer = current_user.customer
    @company = Company.find_by_domain(User.get_domain(@customer.email))          
    super          
  end
end
```

---

I want to pass through the Company ID of the currently logged-in user so I can then view all the users from the same company.

This page will be accessed via a button from the Edit Account page (automatically generated view with Devise). This is the page in which I get the below error:

[image]

Note: I only see this error with the button to 'Manage Users' page. If I comment out that line and look at my logs, I can see this fine:

[image]

**User Model:**

```
   ...
   def self.get_domain(email_address)
     email_address.gsub(/.+@([^.]+.+)/, '\1')
   end

  def confirm!
    current_customer = Customer.where(email: self.email).first        
    super
  end

  def ensure_has_customer
    customer = self.customer
    company = Company.find_by_domain(User.get_domain(self.email))
  end
  ...
```

**User Registration Controller:**

```
class UserRegistrationController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters
  skip_before_filter :load_customer_access, only: [:new, :create]  

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :current_password, :password, :password_confirmation, :email) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :current_password, :password, :password_confirmation, :email) }
  end

  def edit
    super
      @customer = current_user.customer
      @company = Company.find_by_domain(User.get_domain(@customer.email))
      puts "HAPPY CUSTOMER"
      puts @customer.email    
      puts "HAPPY COMPANY"
      puts @company.id // See above screenshot for logs
  end
end
```

**Edit User Route:**

```
match "company/:company_id/edit_users" => 'company#edit_users', via: [:get], :as => :edit_company_users
```

**_edit_account.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for(current_user, :as => :user, :url => registration_path(:user), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
    <div>
      <h1 class="login-header">My Account</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-group col-centered input-group-lg">
          <%= f.text_field :first_name, :class => 'form-control custom-form-control', :placeholder => 'First name' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-group col-centered input-group-lg">              
          <%= f.text_field :last_name, :class => 'form-control custom-form-control', :placeholder => 'Last name' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-group col-centered input-group-lg">              
          <%= f.email_field :email, :autocomplete => "off", :class => 'form-control custom-form-control', :placeholder => 'Email' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-group col-centered input-group-lg">             
          <%= f.password_field :password, :autocomplete => "off", :class => 'form-control custom-form-control', :placeholder => 'New password' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-group col-centered input-group-lg">              
          <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :autocomplete => "off", :class => 'form-control custom-form-control', :placeholder => 'New password confirmation' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-group col-centered input-group-lg">           
          <%= f.password_field :current_password, :class => 'form-control custom-form-control', :placeholder => 'Current password' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <button type="submit" class="btn-account-primary">Update Account</button>
    </div>
<% end %>
<% if @customerAccess.admin_role %>
  <hr>
  <%= link_to 'Manage Users', edit_company_users_path(@company), :class => 'btn btn-sm btn-default' %><br>
<% end %>
```

The code for my Company controller and views can reach the `edit_company_users_path` ok, and the Company controller code is shown below if that's helpful:

**Company Controller:**

```
class CompanyController < ApplicationController    

  def index
    @companies = Company.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @companies }
    end
  end   

  def edit_users
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    @company_name = @company.name
    @domain = @company.domain
    @find_domain = "%" + @domain + "%"
    @users = User.find(:all, :conditions => ["email LIKE ?", @find_domain])
  end
end
```

**Company Index View:**

```
<div class="col-md-12">    
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="page-header">
          <h1>Manage Companies</h1>
        </div>
        <table class = "table table-striped table-bordered">
          <tr>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Domain</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>

          <% @companies.each do |company| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= company.name %></td>
              <td><%= company.domain %></td>
              <td>
                <%= link_to 'Manage Company Access', edit_company_path(company), :class => 'btn btn-sm btn-default' %>
                <%= link_to 'Manage Applications', edit_company_applications_path(company), :class => 'btn btn-sm btn-default' %>
                <%= link_to 'Manage Users', edit_company_users_path(company), :class => 'btn btn-sm btn-default' %><br>
              </td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        </table>
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
```

What's interesting to note is that when I do `<%= @company %>` in the view, no name of the Company appears (though the ID is 2, and name is 'Ryan Drake'), and displays ok in the view. When I do `<%= @company.id %>`, it throws "undefined method 'id' for nil:class".

Any guidance about accessing the company ID from the Edit Account Devise view in the easiest way possible, so I can pass that through as a parameter and hit the method would be superb.

Comment: paste your view code of _edit_account.html.erb

Comment: from where your calling partial _edit_account?

Comment: From which file you are rendering that partial?

Comment: Devise/edit.html.erb

```<div class="container">
  <% if @customerAccess && @customerAccess.your_account %>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="signup-form col-md-4">
          <%= render 'devise/registrations/edit_account' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>```

Comment: have you tried this `edit_company_users_path(@company)`

Comment: Hi Amit, yes I have. It's in the code sample under the heading **_edit_account.html.erb** at the bottom. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Also, as a general advice, you don't need to generate so many instance variables from your controller. You are creating `@company_name`, `@domain` and `@find_domain` directly from `@company`. Just use `@company`, `@company.name`, etc... in your view.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you show, there is an end and a if, I think you are probably closing the "each" loop before the line of the error, so the "company" variable is not found.

EDIT:

I see two potential problems:

1. It is definitely `@company` in `edit_company_users_path(@company)`. If
   it doesn't work, does it show the same error? Please show that.
2. I think you might be messing with devise routes in the alias
   "edit_company_users_path", but I don't know how are you organizing
   your resources. If you are nesting companies under users, the
   default route for that would be something like
   edit_company_users_path(@company, current_user). Run `rake routes` if
   you get a routing error.

Comment: There's two different things going on here: One is the form, which needs a closing end tag and then another conditional based on access: ```<% if @customerAccess.admin_role %>``` . It doesn't look like I'm closing the each loop unless I've missed something? Please point it out clearer.

Comment: @RyanDrake please paste the full Company Index View so we can see the problem.

Comment: Done! There you go :)

Comment: Hey Puce, alright so I've just updated it as I'm now getting a new error. Please see edited screenshot :)

Comment: I've added a screenshot of my logs too, to see it's printing the @company ID fine.

Comment: What's interesting to note is that when I do ```<%= @company %>``` in the view, no name of the Company appears (though the ID is 2, and name is 'Ryan Drake'), and displays ok in the view. When I do ```<%= @company.id %>```, it throws 'undefined method nil for nil:class'. Not sure if that's helpful!